# Cannot add screenshots for my app

Tags: iphone, networking, upload, timeout, app-store-connect

I am trying to add screenshot for my app and in app purchase. Both are unsuccessful.
It says network timed out. But it says this instantly, without trying to upload at all imo.

Answer (score 0):

This happens often. Just try later.. It will work.

Comment: I waited 1 day. Still not working :( Is this also normal? Thank you.

Comment: You are adding these via iTunes connect in your browser right?

Answer (score 0):

Using Safari instead of Firefox works.